# Any way to only show related videos from the same channel using YouTube Player API Android?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to be able to show YouTube videos in my app with related videos only coming from my channel. This can be implemented via the YouTube Iframe API by setting the parameter "rel=0".

Is there any way to achieve this same behavior using the YouTube Android API Player API?

(API for reference https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer)